# Spark on Kubernetes (non EMR) with AWS Glue Data Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am running spark jobs on EKS and these jobs are submitted from Jupyter notebooks.

We have all our tables in an S3 bucket and their metadata sits in Glue Data Catalog.

I want to use the Glue Data Catalog as the Hive metastore for these Spark jobs.
I see that it's possible to do when Spark is run in EMR: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html

but is it possible from Spark running on EKS?

I have seen this code released by aws:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore
but I can't understand if patching of the Hive jar is necessary for what I'm trying to do.
Also I need the hive-site.xml file for connecting Spark to the metastore, how can I get this file from Glue Data Catalog?

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @1shubhamjoshi1 no, not really. We were on very long support case with AWS. At first they sent us the fixed jars, then it required more and more jars to be replaced, we ended up replacing all the spark jars with jars from some EMR build. Then we were able to finally run "show databases" and "show tables". Then we I tried to run a simple select statement the next error was that a scheme of s3 is unidentified, meaning that the path of all our tables defined on the aws glue level was starting with "s3://" and not "s3a://". So this was one of the reasons we are now using Databricks

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for that.

I created a new spark image with this instructions: https://github.com/viaduct-ai/docker-spark-k8s-aws

and finally at my job yaml file, I added some configurations

```
sparkConf:
   ...
    spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl: "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
    spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl: "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
```